# php.ini session.cookie_domain - what to put?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, dns

what should I put in session.cookie_domain in my `php.ini` file?

my domain is: `https://www.domain.com` (with https and www)

I see people put just `domain.com`. what should i put if i have https and www?

here is the code im referring to:

```
; The domain for which the cookie is valid.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-domain
session.cookie_domain =
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `domain.com` mean *only* `//domain.com`.
- `.domain.com` mean `//domain.com` but also `//www.domain.com` or `//subdomain.domain.com`
- If you want to send the cookie *only* over secure connections (https), enable the `session.cookie_secure` option. Otherwise the cookie will be set even if you're using the `http` protocol.

Comment: where did u get this info from?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to reiterate and add some references to the PHP [runtime configuration documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) since this is indeed easy to miss:

The [`session_set_cookie_params`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) documentation states in the Parameters section:

> domain
> Cookie domain, for example 'www.php.net'. To **make cookies
> visible on all subdomains** *then the domain must be prefixed with a dot
> like '.php.net'.

So, we can defer that `.php.net` allows all subdomains *.php.net which also includes http://php.net.